# Moqui connect to Master and Replica database

Tags: moqui

I am new in Moqui and want to connect to two mysql databases, one to write on(master) and one to read from (replica), how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, i used

```
Connection con = ec.entity.getConnection("replica-group-name")
ps = con.prepareStatement("SElECT statement")
rs = ps.executeQuery()
```

this code is doing 50% of what i want, i am now trying to make the `entity-find` to use the replica instead of `transactional` datasource

Comment: Adding support for read replicas has been discussed but is not currently explicitly supported. Usually read replicas are used for reporting and the recommended approach in Moqui for more complex reporting is to feed data to ElasticSearch and query/aggregate there. Still, there would be value in this and chances are it will be added sooner or later.